# SQL query to select records WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot

I was having some problem when trying to write SQL query to filter out certain data. Basically my table design is `1 ward can have many beds, and 1 bed can have many enrollments`.

My `ward table has w_id as PK`, `bed table with b_id as PK and w_id as FK`, `enrollment table with e_id as PK and b_id as FK`.

What I am trying to do now is get the list of beds together with ward details that is not exist in enrollment table. I tried my SQL query in Oracle database:

```
SELECT * FROM bed b
INNER JOIN ward w ON b.WARD_ID = w.ID
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM bed b2 
INNER JOIN enroll e ON e.BED_ID = b2.ID
WHERE b2.ID = b.ID );
```

It did managed to returned me the desired result. However, when I tried to put the above query as native query in Spring Boot, I am getting the error message:

```
Encountered a duplicated sql alias [ID] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query; nested exception is org.hibernate.loader.custom.NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [ID] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM bed b
INNER JOIN ward w ON b.WARD_ID = w.ID
```

It appears the bed and ward table both have columns named `id`. By doing select * you are implicitly including all the columns from both the bed and the ward table. So you are including two columns named `id`. The `not exists` part is a distraction. Some sql clients will allow this, but hibernate is more strict. I don't have an environment to do an immediate test on, but something like the following would fix, if this is the issue.

```
SELECT b.id, b.ward_id, w.ward_name FROM bed b
INNER JOIN ward w ON b.WARD_ID = w.ID
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT b2.id FROM bed b2 
INNER JOIN enroll e ON e.BED_ID = b2.ID
WHERE b2.ID = b.ID );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is related to your problem, but you don't need the `JOIN` in the subquery.  A simpler version is:

```
SELECT *
FROM bed b INNER JOIN
     ward w
     ON b.WARD_ID = w.ID
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM enroll e
                  WHERE e.BED_ID  = b.ID
                 );
```